# cannot see source code section of xcode debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging

In the XCode debugger, I can only see the disassembly code, I do not see the section for source code. I tried the "source code and disassembly" options in Debugger display. Nothing changes. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please post a screen shot of what you do see. From the answers so far it's clear that people have different ideas of what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you check the menus. Visit "Product" > "Debug Workflow" and make sure "Show Disassembly When Debugging" is off. Some rabbit activated it for me...

Answer (score 2):

You're never going to see any source code that you don't have access to. If you're stepping into Apple's territory (or any other vendor's for that matter), all you'll get is disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

You get to the source code by clicking on the method name in the thread window.